# Add/remove aliases on outlook email with python

Tags: python, outlook

I'm trying to make a program that can automatically add aliases to an outlook email or remove one. I found a few python api's but I couldn't find any that supported that. I want the code to be able to replicate this process:
[image]

As you can see in the screenshot it gives me the option to add an alias or remove one, this is what I would like to do automatically with python. Thank you!

Comment: you could use selenium to automate the process of creating an alias for the account using python if speed is not an issue

Comment: ive never used selenium before, can you show an example showing how to use it?

Comment: selenium has really good documentation so definitely check there first https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/ you can also check this page for quick example https://crossbrowsertesting.com/blog/test-automation/automate-login-with-selenium/